# The phase-change associated with a unitary transform

Tags: quantum-mechanics, waves, wavefunction

Say we have a basis of two wave functions $|\psi_1\rangle$ and $|\psi_2\rangle$, and make a unitary transform with the matrix $U=\left[\begin{array}{ll}0 & 1 \\i & 0\end{array}\right]$. This is the same as multiplying one of the wavefunctions by a relative phase $e^{\phi i}$, but what exactly is the phase we are multiplying with? How would it change if the matrix read $U=\left[\begin{array}{ll}0 & 1 \\-i & 0\end{array}\right]$?

Comment: $ \pi \mathrm{i} = e^{\pm \mathrm{i} \pi/2}$ so the first wavefunction is given a phase $\pm \mathrm{i} \pi /2$ relative to the second.

Comment: @ArthurMorris $\pm$, not $\pi$.

Comment: Yep, my mistake!